# Tutorial for using cucumber and rspec with .net apps

Tags: .net, rspec, cucumber

Are there any good tutorials out there for using cucumber and rspec for testing .net applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is on MSDN magazine website:

[Getting Started With IronRuby And RSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434651.aspx)

This article is from InformIT:

[Testing .NET Applications Using IronRuby](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1583174)

Answer (score 2):

This is an awesome (and very recent) Cucumber + Rspec tutorial that covers using Cucumber with Java, .NET, and Ruby. Downloadable as a PDF w/ source code even!

[The Secret Ninja Cucumber Scrolls](http://cuke4ninja.com/)